# Leer datos de Firebase y convertirlos a Markdown

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, markdown

antes que nada muchas gracias desde ya por sus respuestas.

Tengo el siguiente problema:

He guardardo texto en Firestore utilizando la sintaxis de Markdown (Es un pequeño blog)y necesito recuperarlos con Vuejs y mostrarlos mostrando los estilos que me proporciona Markdown, será eso posible?

De antemano, mil gracias a todos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes instalar un plugin para Vuejs, como este [vue3-markdown-it](https://vuejsexamples.com/a-vue-3-markdown-it-wrapper-plugin/) para que formatee y edites tu texto como markdown.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Angy, lo voy a instalar para hacer pruebas.

Comment: Sí, dale @GeeksNatives 